# Invoke Form Validation Manually in Play Framework 2.x

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have a model with several constraint annotations. Is it possible to fill a Form with that model object and then manually invoke validation. I am looking for something like this:

```
models.Photo photo = new models.Photo();
photo.loadValues();
Form<models.Photo> photoForm = new Form<models.Photo>(models.Photo.class);
photoForm.fill(photo);
```

And then I could do something like this:

```
photoForm.validate(); #does not exist
if (photoForm.hasErrors) {
    ...
}
```

**Update**:
estmatic's Answer works pretty well. To convert the object to a Map I use Beanutils:

```
Map<String, String> photoMap = BeanUtils.describe(photo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `fill()`, you can use the `bind()` method and pass in a `Map` with your pre-loaded values. That will trigger the validation like `bindFromRequest` would.

```
Map<String,String> values = loadValues();
Form<models.Photo> photoForm = form(models.Photo.class).bind(values);
if (photoForm.hasErrors()){
  ...
}
```